# How to fix 7z.tmp file created in Windows xp?

Tags: 7-zip

I created large `.7z.tmp` file without noticing the `.tmp` *extension*. Now I can't open it to salvage the files which were not kept elsewhere. I have seen [code by Igore](https://superuser.com/questions/379584/how-to-extract-7z-zip-and-have-correct-directory-strucuture) that looks like it fits this problem but I am not clear how this should be executed.

Can someone assist?

Comment: Can you link this 'code by Igore'?

Comment: Did you try simply renaming the file (ie remove the `.tmp`)?

Comment: I think user117856 meant Igor Pavlov, but I don't know which code.  Maybe some beta bits. I also don't know a way to recover a partial 7z file. The 7-zip program defaults 7z files to be solid and that makes them harder or impossible to recover.

Comment: Thanks for the folowup. Here is the code I was referring to if anyone can help decipher it http://superuser.com/questions/379584/how-to-extract-7z-zip-and-have-correct-directory-strucuture

Comment: Yes,  I did try removing the .tmp as well but it would not open in .7z It is showing a 7+gigabyte size so there are files in it